# Problems with @font-face

Tags: html, css, animation

So my problem is that the fonts used in my nav bar simply won't change and I cannot see the problem with my CSS, please help!

**CSS**

```
//Fonts
@font-face {
    font-family: navfont;
    src: url(fonts/Franchise-Free-Bold.otf);
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style> 
        </style>
        <title>Frost</title>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--navigation panel-->
        <nav id="nav"> 
        <br>
        <p class="navfield">&nbsp;Home Frost Systems&nbsp;</p>
        <br>
        <a name="systems"></a></nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you set that font to be used? `html,body{font-family:'navfont';}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your CSS code is that "navfont" was not in apostrophes or quotation marks so therefore, it was being treated as a value rather than a string. Furthermore, the URL you provided isn't surrounded with the apostrophes/quotations and was also not counted as a string.
As well, you need to declare the font being used for "nav" to correctly display the font.

CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'navfont';
    src: url('fonts/Franchise-Free-Bold.otf');
}
nav{
    font-family: 'navfont';
}
```

An example is located at [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/e5Lyh45j/).

Comment: A font name or an URL don't need quotes as long as there aren't any space or other *strange* characters. It's better to always add them just to be sure but nod needed. `font-family: navfont, arial, verdana, sans-serif` would be fine for example

Comment: It's still not working at all, I included a screenshot at http://gyazo.com/cbfa7f4db1b451cccaf9a8d2ebaee051